# Objective-c.How to properly handle copy of object so it doesn't creates memory leaks?

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, copy, deep-copy

I have some memory leaks and I not quite sure what is causing it, but after some testing, it seems like i screw up at copying my object and it's not released properly. Let me tell you first that I'm using ARC and not so long ago i didn't know much about copies or advance memory management so there still is a lot to learn for me.
Ok let's throw in some details, I have 2 classes Tree and TreeCell.

Tree:

```
@interface Tree : NSObject<NSCopying>

//Here we have 2D array that stores pointers to TreeCell objects
@property (retain,nonatomic)NSMutableArray *tree;

//pointersToTree stores copied pointers from tree, 
//it's the same in terms of content but it have different order of rows and columns
@property (retain,nonatomic)NSMutableArray *pointersToTree;

//i don't believe delegate is relevant to my problems (since it's not copied)
@property (weak,nonatomic) id<treeDelagate>delagate;
…
```

So in short Tree stores 2 the same pointers to each create TreeCell, one of those in each array.

TreeCell:

```
@interface TreeCell : NSObject<NSCopying>

//ancestors and children stores arrays made of 2 NSNubers 
@property (retain,nonatomic)NSMutableArray * ancestors;
@property (retain,nonatomic)NSMutableArray * children;

@property (retain,nonatomic)NSNumber* boardY;
@property (retain,nonatomic)NSNumber* boardX;
...// there are some more Integers and Booleans
```

And here is how copy functions looks like, they are both working but im not sure if they are implemented correctly, so starting with Tree:

```
-(id) copyWithZone: (NSZone *) zone{
    Tree *copy = [[Tree allocWithZone: zone] init];

    //this array will become copy of self.tree
    NSMutableArray* copyOfTree=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    //loop to go thru all stored TreeCell pointers in self.tree
    for (NSInteger a=0; a<self.tree.count; a++) {
     //adding row   
     [copyOfTree addObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc]init]];

        for (NSInteger b=0; b<[self.tree[a] count]; b++) {
            //creating copy of TreeCell and storing pointer to it
            [copyOfTree[a] addObject:[((TreeCell*)self.tree[a][b]) copy]];
        }
    }
    copy.tree=copyOfTree;
    //by now we copied whole self.tree and since i have function to create pointersToTree out of it I call it below
    [copy creatArryOfPointer_Rows:self.pointersToTree.count columns:[self.pointersToTree[0]count]];

    return copy;

}
```

So what I'm trying to get here is deep copy of Tree. Ok here is TreeCell copy function:

```
-(id) copyWithZone: (NSZone *) zone{

    //we start here by allocating and setting NSNubers boardY and boardX
    TreeCell* copy = [[TreeCell allocWithZone: zone] initWithLayer:self.layer boardX:self.boardX andBoardY:self.boardY];

    //after that some integers and booleans are set
    copy.helper=self.helper;
    copy.inTree=self.inTree;
    copy.stableConnected=self.stableConnected;
    copy.positon=self.positon;
    copy.freeStoreg=self.freeStoreg;

   // here we are adding arrays containg 2 NSNumbers
    for (int a=0; a<self.ancestors.count; a++) {
        [copy addAncestorWithX:self.ancestors[a][0] andY:self.ancestors[a][1]];
    }
    for (int a=0; a<self.children.count; a++) {
        [copy addChildWithX:self.children[a][0] andY:self.children[a][1]];

    }

    return copy;

}
```

To make things clear here is addAncestor function addChildren looks the same:

```
-(void) addAncestorWithX:(NSNumber*)ancestorX andY:(NSNumber*)ancestorY{
    if ([self.ancestors indexOfObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:ancestorX,ancestorY, nil]]==NSIntegerMax) {
    [self.ancestors addObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:ancestorX,ancestorY, nil]];
    }
```

Finally this piece of code that creates memory leak:

```
for (NSInteger a=0; a<8000; a++) {
         Tree* testTree =[self.startingTree copy];
}
```

At the end of each cycle of this loop testTree should be released, after testing I'm 100% sure that dealloc for it is called and it's also called for each TreeCell that was stored in tree. But memory usage is constantly increasing. Please tell me where did i go wrong. Some paraboly go and say try serializing it but it doesn't cut it for my.

Comment: Man, I'm trying to parse through, but it breaks my brain, you have a class called tree, that also has a property called tree? So you end up at some point with a line that basically says "a copy of an object of class Tree, has a property called tree, which is an array, which you are assigning an array called copyOfTree (but this is a copy of the property tree, not the object) into. That's like a who's on first routine. :-)

Comment: Ye maybe naming main class like that wasn't the smartest, but you got it that is exactly what is going on in code. Tree class is all about its property tree which is 2D array, so when i want a copy of class i wont copy of that array therefore copy of every Tree Cell that is in that array (well inside are actually pointers to them). I believe my problem lies somewhere in function copyWithZone for TreeCell, tomorrow i will give it some more testing. It's probably NSNumbers those are always bane of my existence.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have a Retain Cycle, maybe dozens. I don't think most of the copying you're doing is actually necessary, since you end up putting all the same pointers into everything. But as long as you understand what a retain cycle is, you'll sort it out.

Comment: Yes I believe so too. Actually the fact that deallocs are called for TreeCell would mean that there are no more references to that object and its parent which is Tree, so there must be some left to objects inside TreeCell itself, and there aren't that many of them. I hope that's it. Ok since it's 2 AM i will call it for today. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And there i have it! The problem was inside my function for adding children and ancestors.

```
[self.ancestors addObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:ancestorX,ancestorY, nil]];
```

This surely added array that i wanted, but it didn't allocate space for it!

So i changed this code:

```
for (int a=0; a<self.ancestors.count; a++) {
        [copy addAncestorWithX:self.ancestors[a][0] andY:self.ancestors[a][1]];
    }
    for (int a=0; a<self.children.count; a++) {
        [copy addChildWithX:self.children[a][0] andY:self.children[a][1]];

    }
```

Into this:

```
for (int a=0; a<self.ancestors.count; a++) {

        [copy.ancestors addObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc]init]];
        [copy.ancestors[a] addObject:self.ancestors[a][0]];
        [copy.ancestors[a] addObject:self.ancestors[a][1]];

    }
    for (int a=0; a<self.children.count; a++) {

        [copy.children addObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc]init]];
        [copy.children[a] addObject:self.children[a][0]];
        [copy.children[a] addObject:self.children[a][1]];



    }
```

So ye folks my tip is when you need deep copy make sure you allocate new space for all of your arrays , and make sure objects don't point outside when they shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing some bonkers stuff with copying, but I can't exactly tell what your goal is with the copying as it pertains to the actually objects stored in the array, so I could be wrong. Without writing a lot of possible answers and comments. First see if just using this solves your issues:

```
NSMutableArray *someArray = [NSMutableArray array];

NSMutableArray *aCopyOfSomeArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:someArray];
```

Comment: First thank You for effort of going thru this moloch, but this will just create second array with the same pointers, so they will point to the same objects, i need them to point to actually new objects that will be identical to old ones.